# CSS in Divi - Trigger an accordion/toggle to open when clicking on a blurb

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, accordion, divi

I have been using the below to trigger accordion/toggle modules to open when a button is selected, but it ONLY works when the trigger is a button module:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
//open toggle on button click
$('.urbanplanning-appreq-button').on('click', function(event){
    $('#urbanplanning-appreq.et_pb_toggle_1 .et_pb_toggle_title').click();
});
});
```

in which .urbanplanning-appreq-button is the class of the button and #urbanplanning-appreq is the id of the toggle it scrolls to and opens. I can't figure out how to get a solution for when the trigger is a blurb module and not a button. This is what I've written but it is not working:

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#open-urbanplanningcurriculum .et_pb_blurb_0.et_pb_blurb').on('click', function(event){
$('#urbanplanningcurriculum .et_pb_toggle_1 .et_pb_toggle_title').click();
});
});
</script>
```

in which #open-urbanplanningcurriculum is the id of the blurb module (first in the list hence the '0') and #urbanplanningcurriculum is the id of the toggle it should open (second in the list hence the '1'). Any tips for what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you posted your CSS and HTML as well in order to better help.

Comment: What CSS and HTML might be missing? Does this need more than just the ids and classes to troubleshoot? Forgive my ignorance as I've only been doing this level of coding for a few months.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Instead of triggering a click, I needed to remove the class that keeps the toggle closed and add the class that opens the toggle:

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#open-urbanplanningcurriculum a').on('click', function(event){
$('#urbanplanningcurriculum').removeClass('et_pb_toggle_close').addClass('et_pb_toggle_open'); return false;
});
});
</script>
```